# How to solve this functional equation: $f(1-f(x))=1-x^{9}, f(1)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

I have managed to guess one solution of this function : $f(x)=1-x^{3}$, but I have no idea how to prove it unique, or get other solutions.

If this is not solvable, how can you prove this function have negative derivative at interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: Hey do you have any more hypothesis ? Like if f is reversible or something else ? Post the exact exercise please

Comment: I see four solutions, but only one satisfying the "initial conditions".

Answer (score 3):

A hint:

Consider the function $g(x):=1-f(x)$.

Comment: Got it! $g(g(x))=x^{9}$, many thanks!

Comment: @Nick: you already new this, as you found the solution $1-x^3$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, I thought this form could help me proving the uniqueness, but still working on it

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes you are right, it is not trivial